# Where are files downloaded when joining servers in Garry's Mod stored on Linux?

Tags: steam, linux, garrys-mod

I joined a couple of Garry's Mod servers using the game's native Linux client and noticed that it downloaded multiple gigabytes of files while doing so. I believe it said it downloaded these from the Steam Workshop, however I do not see any new subscriptions there. Where are these files stored on Linux, and what's the best way to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Steam Community guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=336428778) for that. It's from 2014, but still active.

- Go to `.../Steam/steamapps/common/GarrysMod/garrysmod`. On Linux it should be inside `~/.steam` by default, on Windows `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam` (just `C:\Program Files\Steam` on 32-bit Windows), and on Mac `~/Library/Application Support/Steam`.
- Delete the entire cache folder, or just the contents.
- Delete the **contents of** the following folders at your discretion: downloads, download, Demos, Saves Screenshots, Videos, Dupes. The download folder is things received directly from servers and the downloads folder is Steam Workshop content.